# Help me choose: Olympus OM-D EM-5, Fujy X-Pro1, Sony Nex 7, or?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, travel, mirrorless, micro-stock

I'm a owner of a Sony A700 with some good lenses and a Sony NEX5 with the kit lens but I'm not happy.

The A700 is too big and heavy, and the lenses too, and I can't stand the lack of an OVF/EVF on the Nex 5 (plus the kit lens is not so good). SO I want to sell it all and buy a good mirrorless body with a couple of lenses (I'm considering also primes). (or a good apsc sized compact camera?)

**Key factor I'm looking for:**

- small and lightweight
- built like a tank (it's gonna be a travel camera also)
- good image quality (at least to be able to submit to micro/macrostock websites)
- good manual controls

I need help choosing the right camera, so there are the pros and cons I've found so far on the cameras I like. What are your pros and cons of those camera? Do you have any other camera to suggest? Price is not really an issue (ok... maybe I can't afford a Leica  )

I'm trying to stick to their lenses, because I don't want to use a converter (another piece of crap to carry around, and it adds weight and size)

**Olympus OM-D EM-5 + 17mm f/2.8 + 45mm f/1.8**

Pros:

- i like the design
- small and lightweight
- weather resistant (good while I'm traveling - big pro)
- best price of the three

Cons:

- image quality (?) due to a smaller sensor

**Fujy X-Pro1 + 18mm f/2 + 35mm f/1.4 (how is the 18-55?)**

Pros:

- i really like the design
- image quality

Cons:

- expensive
- slower autofocus (?)
- a little bit bigger

**Sony Alpha Nex 7 + 15mm f/2.8 + 50mm f/1.8**

Pros:

- image quality
- reasonable price

Cons:

- don't really like the design

What do you suggest? Any other camera (even very hi-quality compact caperas with bigger sensor) or lens that I should consider?
Maybe **Sony Nex 6** or **Fuji X-E1**?

Comment: It looks like you already did the comparison and the rest of your question is too vague. We have no idea what you shoot and your photography style.

Comment: Does the Sony RX-100 fit the bill? Very portable, huge sensor for the camera with lens size.

Comment: nope, 20mpixel on a 1" sensor? not gonna happen ;) and it doesn't even have an ovf/evf

Comment: Sorry, but "Cons:

    image quality (?) due to a smaller sensor" is not the case at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 3 models represent the pinnacle of MILCs available in the market right now, so very difficult to pick one.

I'll focus on the key factors you're looking for:

**small and lightweight**

- The Sony NEX-7 is by far the smallest and lightweight of these. The Olympus and Fuji are more or less equivalent in terms of weight.

**built like a tank**

- The Olympus would have the edge here with its full magnesium alloy weather sealed body. Although the build quality of the other models is also pretty close with the NEX-7 having a magnesium alloy body (with some plastic) and the X-Pro1 having a die case aluminium alloy body.

**good image quality**

- Its very difficult to choose between these 3 models in terms of IQ. I would call this one a tie.

**good manual controls**

- I haven't used any of these models, so can't be 100% sure about this, but from the product pictures, the X-Pro1 seems to have the most manual controls.

Apart from these, few other important points to consider:

- The Olympus has the most extensive lens availability for any MILC system.
- The X-Pro1 seems to have a very limited lens range so far, and the ones available seem to be very expensive.
- The Olympus has a smaller sized sensor (half the size of APS-C) compared to the other 2 models making to more difficult to achieve out of focus backgrounds.
- Reviews seem to indicate that the X-Pro1 has slower and unreliable AF system compared to the other models.
- The Sony NEX-7 seems to have the best video performance of the lot.
- The X-Pro1 is considerably more expensive than the other two.
- You should be able to use your A700 lenses on the NEX-7 using the A-mount adaptor.

I would suggest you go to a store and give all these models a try and choose the one that feels the best.

Comment: Most of this is not entirely correct... but the main point about the *lens lineups is key*. The size difference between each is 2cm in one dimension: The E-M5 is 2cm taller than the NEX-7 and the X-Pro1 is 2cm wider than the E-M5. However, the OM-D makes a much smaller system since its lenses can be smaller, other than the 12-50mm F/3.5-5.6 which I find over-sized. Having had all of these, I can say the X-Pro1 feels much more bulky. The OM-D has the most manual controls actually. X-Pro1 clearly leads in image quality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can make this decision for you. I've used the first two on your list, and they are very quirky cameras. Depending on how these quirks mesh with your *personal* quirks, you will love them or hate them. I actually have a site blog post in progress about this — I'll try to finish it up this weekend.

It's not exactly cheap, but if you can rent each of these for a week (not just handle them in the store — that's almost worse than nothing because you have no time to learn the quirks!), you'll be able to *know* what is right for you.